# 4xx Response from server doesn't include JSON data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, validation

I've got a .NET MVC site that uses JSON to perform AJAX form Posts. If a validation error occurs (ie user misses a required field etc), then the server returns the validation errors in a JSON object and sets the HTTP status code of the response to something in the 400 range. On our local machines, this works absolutely fine.

However on our CI environment, it has suddenly stopped working, without any code changes. The response comes back from the server with the correct HTTP code, but the content is not the JSON our controller returns, but the standard .NET error page HTML, ie just the 11-byte 'Bad Request' response if the status code is 400.

The error code is correct for each validation error, so we are hitting the right controller/action, and the validation is working correctly, but for some reason our JSON is getting snipped out. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: The fact that your server returns codes in the 400 range for a *successful* validation (even though the *results* might indicate that the item is actually not valid) is a flagrant misuse of HTTP. Return 200 OK like you should be doing in the first place and the problem magically goes away.

Comment: So is there a more appropriate code to use? Or is it better to include a 'success' field in the JSON and return 200 even when validation fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 400 code because your request syntax in not correct. Check if you have actually encode json data correctly or not.